# Why does Perl treat a hash element as list context at declaration?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Given this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo {
    return wantarray ? () : "value1";
}

my $hash = {
    key1 => foo(),
    key2 => 'value2'
};

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($hash);
```

I get the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'key1' => 'key2',
  'value2' => undef
};
```

When I would expect:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2'
};
```

I understand that a hash is kind-of an even-sized array (as evidenced by the "Odd number of elements in hash assignment" warning I'm getting) but a hash element can only be a scalar, **why would the compiler be giving it array context?**

I found this using the param function of the CGI module when assigning directly to a hash.  The foo() function above was a call to CGI::param('mistyped_url_param') which was returning an empty array, destroying (rotating?) the hash structure.

Comment: an unrelated point: you don't need that '-w' in the shebang line anymore, the 'use warnings' replaces that. (although -w turned on warnings for all packages loaded, not just in the current scope)

Comment: fair enough, that's one of those old habits that doesn't go away easily... vi xxx.pl; #!/usr/bin/perl -w; it just flows :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fat comma isn't a special hash assignment operator. It just a piece of syntactic sugar that means "auto-quote the previous thing"

So:

```
my $hash = {
    key1 => foo(),
    key2 => 'value2'
};
```

Means:

```
my $hash = {
    'key1', foo(), 'key2', 'value2'
};
```

… which is a list and, as willert says:

> every expression in a list is evaluated in list context. You can get around this by calling `scalar foo()`

Comment: While that's true, why is `foo()` evaluated in array context there, when it seems to be clearly an *element* of a list?

Comment: @Greg: because there is no such thing as 'array context'. Void, scalar and list is (mostly) all you get from pure-perl. And list context is equivalent to what you seem to think of as 'array context'

Comment: Unless you reference the array, it is evaluated to its contents. So for 'my @a1 = (1, 2); my @a2 = (@a1, 3, 5, 8);', the second statement is evaluated as '((1, 2), 3, 5, 8)' and the length of @a2 is 5, not 4. An empty list is effectively ignored.

Comment: @willert: With a Perl keyword like `wantarray`, one might assume that the names "list context" and "array context" are interchangeable. At least I don't see any possible confusion. Still, that doesn't answer my question of why `foo()` is called in a *list* context there.

Comment: Every expression in a list is evaluated in list context. You can get around this by calling "scalar foo()", though.

Comment: @Greg for `%hash = ( one => 1, two => 2 )` to work, it has to be a list context.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Loosely speaking, Perl interprets the call to `foo()` as a slice, not an element. It's perfectly valid for `foo()` to return a list of values which the hash initialization will use as key/value pairs.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, I think that answers my question.

Comment: `wantarray` is an unfortunate legacy name.

Comment: Good discussion... Although to me it looks like a leaky implementation in Perl.  The fat comma is aware of context - it stringifies the bare word on the left-hand side (even when it's a constant). I guess it'd be nice if it applied the scalar context to the right-hand side as well, since not doing so breaks the hash.

Answer (score 3):

An anonymous hash constructor supplies list context to the things inside it because it expects a list of keys and values. It's that way because that's the way it is. We don't have a way to represent a Perl hash in code, so you have to use a list where we alternate keys and values. The `=>` notation helps us visually, but performs no magic that helps Perl figure out hashy sorts of things.

Current context propogates to subroutine calls, etc just like it does in any other situation.

This allows you to build hashes with list operations:

```
 my $hash = { 
      a => 'A',  
      map( uc, 'd' .. 'f' ),
      return_list( @args ), 
      z => 'Z' 
      };
```

If you need something to be in scalar context, just say so using `scalar`:

```
 my $hash = { 
      a => 'A',  
      map( uc, 'd' .. 'f' ),
      'g' => scalar return_item( @args ), 
      z => 'Z' 
      };
```